# Format local time to custom time

Tags: momentjs

I have a saved time that is in the format of this: `moment().format('llll')`.

I want to convert that time to this format: `YYYYMMDD`?

I tried this:

```
let Time = moment().format('llll')
moment(Time, 'YYYYMMMDD')
```

That results in `moment.invalid(/* 2019年7月4日星期四 16:03 */)`

Anyone an idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`moment().format('llll')` gives you a formatted string.

To create a moment object with a formatted string, you should also provide the string format.

```
let Time = moment().format('llll')
moment(Time, 'llll')
```

After that, you can easily format moment object as string

```
moment(Time, 'llll').format('YYYYMMMDD')
```